# UpdateTextStyle Request Clearing Bold When Setting fontFamily

Tags: google-docs-api

I am trying to update the font of a range of text in a Google Docs document using the API. I am trying to change just the font and not the font size or style attributes like bold or italic. So if for example I have a document with just the text below as the content:

***Hello*** world

I want to change just the font for the word Hello but leave it the same size and still bold and italic.

I tried to accomplish this with the following code documents.batchUpdate request

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateTextStyle": {
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 6
        },
        "textStyle": {
          "weightedFontFamily": {
            "fontFamily": "Times New Roman"
          }
        },
        "fields": "weightedFontFamily"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The result is a successful response from the server but when I check the document I see it changed the font keeping the size and italic attribute, but it didn't keep the bold attribute. I have also tried this using the Google API Explorer and can reproduce the same results.

My question is how do I change the font without loosing the bold? It seems like it should be possible as it kept the italic attribute in tact. Why is bold different? Is it a bug?

My goal is to just change the font leaving the other attributes as is so I do not want to set bold or other attributes explicitly. I also don't want to have to determine the attributes before hand and reset them. That is more work and will be slower and shouldn't be necessary if italic is maintained.

I am able to do something very similar without issue in Google Sheets using a repeatCell.cell.userEnteredFormat.textFormat.fontFamily request and it maintains the bold and italic.

Thanks in advance for any insight or help.

Comment: When `weightedFontFamily` is used as the fields, `bold` is not modified. So in the current stage, I think that it might be a bug. How about reporting it to the Google issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) And, I think that as the current workaround, how about setting the bold style after `weightedFontFamily` is used? I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. I suspected it was probably a bug but I usually err on the side of making sure I am not doing anything wrong or missing anything first. I used the link to report the potential bug to Google.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In order to show the current situation, how about posting your replying as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do I change the font without loosing the bold?

**Answer**

You have to first save the font weight and bold settings for the range of text you want to modify. There may be more then one font setting for the range. To get the font weight and bold settings for the range you must first check textRun.textStyle. If not defined there you must lookup the paragraphs namedStyleType and check it for the weight and bold settings. If not defined there you must check the NORMAL_TEXT namedStyleType. If not defined there you must use the Google Docs editor default value which for weight is 400 and bold is false.

Once you have the font info for the range you make make a requests for each different font. The request would be like the one in the original question but would set the weightedFontFamily.weight and the bold attributes based on the saved font info.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateTextStyle": {
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 6
        },
        "textStyle": {
          "weightedFontFamily": {
            "fontFamily": "Times New Roman"
            "weight": savedWeight
          },
          "bold": savedBold
        },
        "fields": "weightedFontFamily"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Why is bold different?

**Answer**

The Google Docs API uses weightedFontFamily where the weight sub-attribute defaults to 400 and not the current font weight. The bold setting just increases the weight, so bold and weight are linked. There is no current way in the API to set just the font leaving weight/bold alone.

Is it a bug?

**Answer**

Based on a reply from @Tanaike I have reported the issue to Google via the Google Issue Tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/165029692). They informed me it was working as intended.